# What is the dimension of this subvariety of the Grassmannian?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, grassmannians, krull-dimension

Well, actually, what are the dimensions of the following *two* subvarieties of the Grassmannian. Let $N$ be a positive integer.

1. Let $V \subseteq \mathbb{C}^N$ be a linear subspace of dimension $N-k$ for some positive inter $k \leq N$. What is the dimension of the subvariety of $Gr(k,\mathbb{C}^N)$ consisting of those subspaces $W$ for which $V \cap W \neq \{0\}$?
2. Let $d$ and $l$ be positive integers with $l \leq N$. What is the dimension of the subvariety of
   $$
   Gr\Bigg(\binom{l+d-1}{d},S^d(\mathbb{C}^N)\Bigg)
   $$

consisting of those subspaces that have a basis

$$\tag{1}
\{v_{a_1} \cdot \dots \cdot v_{a_d} : a_1\leq a_2\leq \dots\leq a_d \in \{1,\dots, l\}\}
$$
for some $v_1,\dots, v_l \in \mathbb{C}^N$? Here, $S^d(\mathbb{C}^N)$ denotes the symmetric subspace of $(\mathbb{C}^N)^{\otimes d}$, and the product $\cdot$ appearing in the above set is the symmetric product,
$$
v_{a_1} \cdot \dots \cdot v_{a_d}=\frac{1}{d!} \sum_{\sigma \in S_d} v_{a_{\sigma(1)}} \otimes \dots \otimes v_{a_{\sigma(d)}}.
$$

Comment: The first locus is a hypersurface.

Comment: Thanks, now I see this is obvious as it is the zero locus of a single determinant. Any idea what the dimension is if $V$ has dimension $r<N-k$?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your second definition. Are you describing subspaces of the form $S^d(W)$ for $W \subseteq \mathbb{C}^N$ itself a subspace of dimension $l$? If so, that is a copy of $Gr(l, N)$, $S^d(-)$ is functorial. This is similar to a Veronese map.

Comment: For the first one, this is a Schubert variety, specifically the Schubert variety corresponding to a partition with one row. If $V$ has dimension $r = N - k + 1 - c$ (so $c=1$ is the hypersurface case), the partition is $\lambda = (c)$ and the locus has codimension $c$ in $Gr(k,N)$.

Comment: @JakeLevinson Thanks, you're right about the second one. I'm also interested in the dimension when you remove $\{v_{a}^{d}: a \in [s]\}$ from the set (1), for some $s \leq l$.

Comment: That sounds trickier to me, in particular I think the resulting subspace no longer depends only on $\mathrm{span}(v_1, \ldots, v_l)$.

Comment: Relatedly, I also don't think that gives a closed subset of $Gr(-, S^d(\mathbb{C}^N))$.