# Given a subspace $U \subseteq S^d(V)$ of a particular form, does there always exist a complement of the form $S^d(W)$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, grassmannians

Let $V$ be a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space of dimension $N \geq 2$, let $d$ be a positive integer, let $l < N$ be a positive integer, and let $U \subseteq S^d(V)$ be a linear subspace of codimension $k=\binom{l+d-1}{d}$. Suppose that there exists a basis of $U$ of the form $\{u_1^{\vee d},\dotsc, u_r^{\vee d}\}$ such that
$$
\operatorname{span}\{u_1^{\vee d-1},\dotsc, u_r^{\vee d-1}\}=S^{d-1}(V),
$$
where $r=\binom{N+d-1}{d}-k$.
Does there exist a linear subspace $W \subseteq V$ of dimension $l$ for which $S^d(V)=U \oplus S^d(W)$?

Here, $\vee$ denotes the symmetric product.

This is a variant of my previous question [Given a subspace $U \subseteq S^d(V)$, does there always exist a complement of the form $S^d(W)$?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/415782/150898), which did not assume any particular form for $U$.

Comment: Just to be curious : are there any (geometric or algebraic) motivations behind this question? Does it come from studying Lefschetz type results for Jacobian rings or something related?

Comment: If a subvariety $X \subseteq V$ is s.t. $I(X)$ is generated by degree-d polynomials, then $U_X=\text{span}\{u^{\vee d} : u \in X\}$ is of the specified form, and any linear subspace $W \subseteq V$ for which $U_X \cap S^d(W)=\{0\}$ satisfies the property that $X \cap W=\{0\}$. In general, checking whether $X \cap W=\{0\}$ seems computationally intractable, but now we can do it efficiently when $\dim(W)$ is small enough. I want to know what the maximum possible dimension of $W$ is that this method can handle (the method will then be able to handle a generic $W$ of this dimension).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is still no and a variant of [my previous counter-example](https://mathoverflow.net/a/415807/37214) will provide a counter-example for this new question.

Let $V = \mathbb{C}^4$ with basis $\{x,y,z,t\}$ and $\mathbb{C}^3 \subset V$ with basis $\{x,y,z\}$. Put $U = S^2 \mathbb{C}^3 \oplus \mathbb{C}\cdot t^2$, a basis of which is given by $\{x^2, y^2, z^2, (x+y)^2, (x+z)^2, (y+z)^2, t^2\}$. This basis satisfies the hypothesis in the question as:
$$ \operatorname{span} \{x,y,z,x+y,x+z,y+z,t \} = V.$$

Note that $\dim U = 7$, $\dim S^2V = 10$ and that for any $W \subset V$ of dimension $2$ (so that $\dim S^2 W = 3$), we have:
$$S^2{\left(\mathbb C^3 \cap W\right)} \subset \left(U \cap S^2W \right),$$
with $\dim \mathbb{C}^3 \cap W \geq 1$.